# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (f(\frac{1}{n}) - g(\frac{1}{n}))$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

Let $f,g : \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R $ be twice differentiable functions in $\Bbb R$. Furthermore :  $f(0) = g(0)$ and   $f'(0) = g'(0)$ .

Prove that the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (f(\frac{1}{n}) - g(\frac{1}{n}))$ converges.

I tried using Lagrange theorem but I got stuck. Also I can't expand $f$, $g$ into a Taylor series because they are not continuously differentiable.

Comment: Maybe you want to consider $f(1/n)-g(1/n)$?

Comment: Continuous differentiability  of first derivative  is not needed. Existence of second derivative is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Let $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\sin x$. Then $\sum (f(\frac  1n) +g(\frac  1 n)) $ has positive terms and $f(\frac  1n) +g(\frac  1 n) \geq \frac  1n$ so the series is divergent.

However we can show that $\sum (f(\frac  1n) -g(\frac  1 n)) $  is convergent. Use Taylor expansion up to  second degree term.

Let $h=f-g$ Then $h(x)=h(0)+h'(0)x+O(x^{2})=O(x^{2})$ as $ x \to 0$ (by second order Taylor expansion). Hence $|h(\frac 1 n)| \leq C(\frac 1 {n^{2}})$ for some constant $C$. Since $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}} <\infty$ it follows that $\sum h(\frac 1 n)$ is convergent.

Comment: can you show me how to solve the question using Taylor expansion up to second degree term.

Comment: @razixxmaster What do you get if you write down the second-order Taylor formula for $f(1/n)-g(1/n)$ about the point $0$?

Comment: @Gary I have added some details.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks. I wanted the OP to do some work though.